# I can not get this string to work in C++

Tags: c++, string, file

I can not figure out why I'm getting compiling errors with the string filename; it says it's "out of scope" I tried using cstrings and that did not work, and I copied a basic string sample code from the textbook and even that did not compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
ifstream file1;

// setting variables up for calculation
string filename;
float average, x;
float total = 0;
float count = 0;
float min = 0;
float max = 0;


//asking for file name
cout << "What is the name of the file you wish to open" << endl;
getline(cin, filename);

// opening file
file1.open(filename);
if (file1.fail())
{
cout << "Failure to open that file, please try again." << endl;
return 0;
}

//reading file 
if (file1.is_open())
{   
while (file1 >> x)
{
    if (x <= min)
    { x = min;
    }
    if (x >= max)
    { x = max;
    }
    total = total + x;
    count++;
    if (file1.eof())
    { break;
    }
}
}
// final calculations and testing 
average = (total / average);
cout << "Minimum = " <<  min << endl;
cout << "Maximmum = " << max << endl;
cout << "The total count = " << count << endl;
file1.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can compile the code, what specific compilation errors did you get?

Comment: Three things to consider: `1` Post the exact error message. `2` Properly format/indent your code. `3` Strip it down to the most minimal code necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Are you compiling with the c++11 flag set?

Comment: The code compiles with no errors here:  http://ideone.com/O6YNVl  Also note the formatting of the code, and how it looks much different than what you posted.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie If I compile the code without c++11, I get an error with using strings in open. http://ideone.com/1QgoIo

Comment: @microtony i received a very long compile error that stated multiple times

"error no matching function for call 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::open(std::strings&)'

Comment: @R.Schulj It looks like the issue is with your compile flags.  Opening a file with a `std::string` was only added in C++11 and later. If you are using `g++` your command line options would look like `g++ -std=c++11 -o executable file1.cpp file2.cpp` or `g++ -std=c++14 -o executable file1.cpp file2.cpp`. You can compare http://ideone.com/1QgoIo and http://ideone.com/VGpgIT.

Comment: The code doesn't need the call to `file1.is_open()`; it's already checked that. And it doesn't need the call to `file1.eof()` because the loop condition checks that input succeeded. And it doesn't need the call to `file1.close()`; `file1`'s destructor will do that. And the assignments are backwards: if `x` is less than `min`, it should change `min`; as written, it changes the value of `x` to match the value of `min`.

Answer (score 2):

Prior to C++ 11, file streams only took `const char*` as file names. With C++ 11 there are overloads for `std::string` as well. If you don't have the overloads, use `filename.c_str()` in the call to `open` to get a pointer to a C-string with the contents of `filename`.